# Storing google map object on page change and redrawing on return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an angular directive that calls a service to create a google map on initial page load and saves the Map object to an array in the service. This works fine.

When the user navigates away from the page and then returns, the directive is supposed to redraw the stored map object but this does not work. I am able to create the map, draw it on first page load, save it to an array, and retrieve it from the array, but when I call `google.maps.event.trigger(self.map, 'resize');` nothing happens even though self.map is a google map object.

Is it possible to save the map object to an array and redraw it on returning to the page or do I have to create a new map object each time?

Here is how I am trying to achieve this:

**From the directive**

```
if(aggMapServ.maps[$scope.options.index] instanceof google.maps.Map) {
    self.map = aggMapServ.maps[$scope.options.index];
    console.log(self.map); // This is logging a google map object
    google.maps.event.trigger(self.map, 'resize');
}else {
    self.map = aggMapServ.makeMap($scope.options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. When I inspected the map element in the browser I noticed that it was empty whenever I returned to the page but if I logged `self.map.getDiv();` to the console, it would show me the old map element with all the google map child elements. So what was happening was, although `self.map` was a google map object it was still referencing the old dom element that no longer was on the page.

So after some trial and error, I found all I had to do was remove the empty map element and replace it with the one returned by `self.map.getDiv()`. I'm not sure if I'm doing things right but it works so any input greatly appreciated. Here is my code now:

```
.directive('aggMap', function(aggMapServ, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'options': '=options'
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div id="{{divId}}"></div><div ng-transclude></div>',
        controllerAs: 'map',
        controller: function () {
            this.map = {};
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var emptyElem, cachedElem;

            var watcher = scope.$watch('options', function(value) {
                if(value !== undefined) {
                    scope.divId = (value.mapId === undefined) ? 'map-canvas' : value.mapId;
                    $timeout(function() {
                        if(aggMapServ.maps[scope.options.index] instanceof google.maps.Map) {
                            ctrl.map = aggMapServ.maps[scope.options.index];
                            emptyElem = angular.element(document.getElementById(scope.divId));
                            cachedElem = ctrl.map.getDiv();

                            emptyElem.remove();
                            elem.append(cachedElem);
                        }else {
                            ctrl.map = aggMapServ.makeMap(scope.options);
                        }
                    }, 0);
                    watcher();
                }
            });

            elem.on('$destroy', function () {
                google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(window);
                google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(document);
                google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(ctrl.map)
            });
        }
    };
})
```